# Passing Class as an argument to an image click event Handler

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have a Trip object which I am getting from list TripsByTripIds which I want to pass as a parameter to image click event handler down below. how do I pass it?

```
  foreach (Tripclass Trip in TripsByTripIds )
  {
      ImageButton imageButton = new ImageButton();
      imageButton.ImageUrl = "~/" +Trip.CorridorName+"/"+Trip.Time+"/"+Trip.ImgFileName;
      imageButton.Height = Unit.Pixel(100);
      imageButton.Style.Add("padding", "5px");
      imageButton.Width = Unit.Pixel(100);
      imageButton.Click += new ImageClickEventHandler(imageButton_Click);
      AMSPanel1.Controls.Add(imageButton);
      AMSPanel1.Height = Unit.Pixel(860);
  }

  protected void imageButton_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs fi)
  {
      testimage.ImageUrl = ((ImageButton)sender).ImageUrl;
      lblTime.Text = Trip.Time; 
      lblLocation.Text = Trip.Location; //can't access trip object here
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found answer from one of posts in stack overflow the other day.i haven't saved that link though. but the solution below solves my problem

```
  foreach (Tripclass Trip in TripsByTripIds )
  {
      ImageButton imageButton = new ImageButton();
      imageButton.ImageUrl = "~/" + Trip.CorridorName + "/" + Trip.Time + "/" + Trip.ImgFileName;
      imageButton.Height = Unit.Pixel(100);
      imageButton.Style.Add("padding", "5px");
      imageButton.Width = Unit.Pixel(100);
      imageButton.Click += new ImageClickEventHandler((a, b) => imageButton_Click(a, b,Trip));
      AMSPanel1.Controls.Add(imageButton);
      AMSPanel1.Height = Unit.Pixel(860);
  }

  protected void imageButton_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e, Tripclass Trip)
  {
      testimage.ImageUrl = ((ImageButton)sender).ImageUrl;
      lblTime.Text = Trip.Time; 
      lblLocation.Text = Trip.Location; //I can access trip object here
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If it can be represented as text, you can add your value to [CommandArgument](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.imagebutton.commandargument(v=vs.110).aspx) property

Comment: ReviewTrip  is class of type ReviewTripDC. I do not think it can be represented as text.

Comment: @avi as I see, you only need one property `ReviewTrip.Time`

Comment: that is an example.but I  need to access several other properties of ReviewTripDC in my event. I did not want to write all of them so that it won't become long question